KiCAD: remove DNP components from paste layer
We have an adapter board that works as an interface between our own and third-party electronics. Depending on the third-party configuration about a third of somewhat expensive components may be unused. I've prepared two versions of BOM and placement files to order required boards by simply removing unused parts from one version.
What I would like is to get rid of solder blobs on not populated pads. Is there a way to exclude DNP parts from paste layer without making alternative footprints for all of them?

It means producing multiple stencils. That might be an interesting feature.

Sorry to ask, but why do you want the solder removed? That's rather unusual

He wants the solder paste removed from certain specific pads @tobalt (that's my reading of it anyway)

@tobalt I can say it's for aesthetic reasons, but really I do not see the solder on any commercial boards with unpopulated SMD pads, just bare HASL

@SimonRichter I rather hoped this feature is so trivial it has been implemented already. Maybe it is supported in paid software, but I am using free one for now. I guess it depends on whether the software supports a concept of DNP. Then it should be simple to add a check box "remove DNP parts from paste layers"

@Maple I see. My experience is the exact opposite hence my question ‍♂️ I see unpopulated but soldered pads all the time.

@Maple some variant handling exists, but it's not propagated to the output plots

The easiest option is to simply save the design file under a different name and then delete the unused components.  Ensure the desired components are not moved.  Don't worry about broken or missing traces - you won't be using the copper Gerber files.
Generate the Gerber files again and keep only the Solder Paste files.

I like that answer.

Oh, this is simple! The best thing about this solution is that removing DNP components is relatively quick, so I can keep only full schematics without worrying about copying future changes into two different projects. What is even better, is that I can generate shortened BOM and placement files at the same time instead of going over them manually.


Is there a way to exclude DNP parts from paste layer without making
alternative footprints for all of them?

I've just had a go (KiCAD 7) and nothing is giving a solution so, my only recommendation is to use Gerber editor software. KiCAD's inbuilt viewer does what it says on the tin i.e. it's just a viewer. I hope someone can come up with a better solution then I'll delete this.
Possibly, you could plot a user-defined layer in which you draw boxes where the paste is not to be applied (and give instructions to the PCB house to process things following those extra instructions). This is doable if a little clunky.

It would be a bit of a task but you could write a script to do this.
The script would open the kicad_pcb file, and search for the attributes smd & dnp, and if a part has both delete the paste layers from its pads. Depending on how often you do this, and how proficient you are at scripting there would be a break-even point where this is worth the time. You could either save this as a separate file, or you could keep it. The DRC will give the warning "... does not match the footprint in the library", and any time you want to undo this you just need to update the footprints back to the library version.
